# VSCode change working directory to python file path in terminal

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Before somebody asks yes this is a duplicate but all the solutions were 2-3 years old and I tried them all.

The problem is that my launch.json is in the parent directory, so if I execute a file in a child directory and access a file stored in that child file directory, python throws an error, "File not Found".

The current latest solution according to other questions is to go to the python extension settings and tick `Terminal : Execute in File Dir`. which I already did. But the working directory is still not correct. I tried os.getcwd() and it still returns the path of the parent directory.

Anybody has a solution for it?

Answer (score 0):

You could try changing the content inside `launch.json`
from

```
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
```

to this

```
            "cwd": ""
```

Comment: there's no cwd in my launch.json from defualt, but I'll try that 

EDIT: and nope it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

**cwd:**

> Specifies the current working directory for the debugger, which is the
> base folder for any relative paths used in code. If omitted, defaults
> to ${workspaceFolder} (the folder open in VS Code).

You needn't change the `cwd` configuration. Just need to modify the relative path to the file which you want to reference.

You can refer to the [official docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging), it has a detailed example.

Comment: I can do that but still not really a solution if I want to run the file in any other editor.

Comment: @Shaleen Agarwal I mean, you need not change the cwd configuration, just remember to reference the file with the right relative path. You should know the default path of cwd was the ${workspaceFolder} (the folder open in VS Code).

Comment: that's what I meant that for vscode it might work, but if I need to open the folder on another system. I'll again need to modify the path as the relative pathing (in regards to the workspace folder) wont work there. it's just a workaround not a true solution and tbh its ridiculous that I even have to search for such a basic thing

Comment: @Shaleen Agarwal I tried in the PyCharm, it also needs to configure the 'working directory' configuration to set the value of 'os.getcwd()'. In the VSCode, you just need to remember the default value of the 'os.getcwd()' was the ${workspaceFolder} (the folder open in VS Code). That's enough. And when you continue the project in other editor, just need to set the related configuration the same to the VSCode, everything will be ok.

Comment: Thanks for the help but you didnt get my point. it's just a workaround, another workaround which is even easier is to just make a launch config in the script folder, then you wont even need to do anything but again in the end its just a workaround and as for remembering relative paths, will you keep setting it again and again for every editor around?

Comment: @Shaleen Agarwal Have you read my answer? you need not do anything. You need not configure at all. just set the path relative to the ${workspaceFolder} (the folder open in VS Code).